# Why am I getting access violation errors when nesting aura:if?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When multiple `aura:if` are nested together, I'm getting an error like the following:

> Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'value2' of component 'markup://c:demo1 {1:0}'
>         is not visible to 'markup://aura:if {6:0}'.

## Example Reproduction

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="value1" type="String" access="private" />
    <aura:attribute name="value2" type="String" access="private" />
    <lightning:input value="{!v.value1}" label="Value 1" placeholder="Enter 'a'" />
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.value1 eq 'a'}">
        <lightning:input value="{!v.value2}" label="Value 2" placeholder="Enter 'b'" />
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.value2 eq 'b'}">
            <lightning:input label="Value 3" value="{!join(' ',v.value1,v.value2)}" />
        </aura:if>
    </aura:if>
</aura:application>
```

This occurs when the attribute is private, and there's at least two levels of `aura:if` statements. It also only occurs after causing the innermost `lightning:input` to render, then subsequently unrendering it by changing Value 1 a few times. Once this happens, all further renderings will cause this error.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug with access checking in the Lightning Web Component framework, and may manifest as an error in Aura components when this happens. There are a few different ways to reproduce it; the one in the answer is just one form. The known solutions are as follows:

## Make The Attribute Public

The access exception will only occur on private attributes.

## Avoid aura:if

The way aura:if rerenders causes the bug to surface in LWC. Instead, hide the elements using normal CSS (or SLDS). Here's an example fix:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="value1" type="String" access="private" />
    <aura:attribute name="value2" type="String" access="private" />
    <lightning:input value="{!v.value1}" label="Value 1" placeholder="Enter 'a'" />
    <div class="{!v.value1 eq 'a'?'':'slds-hide'}">
        <lightning:input value="{!v.value2}" label="Value 2" placeholder="Enter 'b'" />
        <div class="{!v.value2 eq 'b'?'':'slds-hide'}">
            <lightning:input label="Value 3" value="{!join(' ',v.value1,v.value2)}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

## Avoid Usage of LWC Components

Using any component that is a LWC component (basically anything in the lightning namespace) can result in this error. You can replace it with the basic ui namespace component (e.g. ui:inputText instead of lightning:inputText). This will probably not be practical in most applications, but it is a possible workaround.

This has been filed as W-5722782.